# Search elements by partial id tag via for loop

Tags: javascript

So i have this svg map with streets that all contain the streetname in a id  tag. I want to have an searchfield that searches the streets by matching the searchinput partially with the id of the street. Now i have a few problems with my code. First it searches with case sensitive, second the ids have a underscore for each space, these need to be replaced by spaces in the search and lastly when i have a positive search it colors the street but if i remove the search the streets keeps having the highlighted color.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
   var searchvalue = document.getElementById("searchfield").value;
   document.querySelector("[id*="+searchvalue+"]").style.stroke = "yellow";}
```

[Now i lookedup some solutions and one is to make a for loop that checks every element for these criteria](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp) however my svg includes multiple tagnames like "line" "path" and "polygon" So i coulden't figure out how to do this.

[Here is my full html code](https://codepen.io/Mika_vd_wiel/pen/gVGNGP)

Comment: can you provide some html

Comment: @AimalKhan, i just did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you need here is to assign class to search items then next time when you search remove styles and that class from all the highlighted paths. and for search first split the path with spaces and then capitalize the string and join it again with underscores i.e

```
function changeFunction(event){
  console.log(event);
  var searchvalue = event.split(' ').map(element => element.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join('_');   
  document.querySelectorAll('.searched').forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute('style');
    element.removeAttribute('class');
 });
 if(searchvalue) { 
    document.querySelectorAll("[id*="+searchvalue+"]").forEach(( element) => {
        element.style.stroke = "green";
        element.setAttribute('class', 'searched');
    });

  }  
}
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yftacp5d/1/)

Comment: Thanks it worked, one more quick question, do u maybe know how to jump the the result if there is only one result left?

Comment: sorry i am unable to understand your question